# Rebuild dynamically html tag when splitted

Tags: java, html, regex, tags

I need to split my `html` into two parts when a particular variable appears.

Here's an example:

```
<h1>I can have any kind of text here</h1>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><em><strong>When I see this variable :)</strong> I want to rebuild my html.</em></p>
```

What I would like at the end:

```
<h1>I can have any kind of text here</h1>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><em><strong>When I see this</strong></em></p>

<p><em><strong> :)</strong> I want to rebuild my html.</em></p>
```

Here is what I thought (tell me if there is a better way):

1. Split on my variable
2. Get all tags by a regex? (I just know regex to tell me true or false)
3. Put all tags unclosed on a stack?
4. loop twice (array split 1 and array split 2)

EDIT Example 2 :

```
<ol>
<li>
<h2>I can have any kind of text here 1</h2>
</li>
<li>
<h2><strong>I can have any kind of text here 2 variable</strong></h2>
</li>
<li>
<h2><strong>I can have any kind of text here 3</strong></h2>
</li>
<li>
<h2>I can have any kind of text here 4</h2>
</li>
<li><em><strong>When I see this</strong></em></li>
</ol>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

...

```
<ol>
<li>
<h2>I can have any kind of text here 1</h2>
</li>
<li>
<h2><strong>I can have any kind of text here 2 variable </strong></h2>
</li>
</ol>
```

Variable

```
<ol>
<li>
<h2><strong>I can have any kind of text here 3</strong></h2>
</li>
<li>
<h2>I can have any kind of text here 4</h2>
</li>
<li><em><strong>When I see this</strong></em></li>
</ol>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

Exemple 3 :

```
<p><a href="test">I can have any kind of text of varaible here even clickable.</a></p>
```

...

```
<p><a href="test">I can have any kind of text of</a></p>
```

varaible

```
<p><a href="test">here even clickable.</a></p>
```

Comment: Step 5: Forget step 1-4 and use a parser instead?

Comment: there are a lot of html parsers, indeed.

Answer (score 1):

It's well known that you should use a **html parser instead a regex**.

Anyway, you can use a simple string replaceAll to do what you want. If you want to use a regex you can just use something like this:

```
String str = "<h1>I can have any kind of text here</h1>\n<p>&nbsp;</p>\n<p><em><strong>When I see this variable :)</strong> I want to rebuild my html.</em></p>\n"; 
str = str.replaceAll("variable", "</strong></em></p>\n<p><em><strong>"); 
System.out.println(str);
```

**[Working regex](https://regex101.com/r/zT1cU6/1)**

**[IdeOne demo](https://ideone.com/0G8McJ)**

Output

```
<h1>I can have any kind of text here</h1>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><em><strong>When I see this </strong></em></p>
<p><em><strong> :)</strong> I want to rebuild my html.</em></p>
```

Comment: But the html is unknown/dynamic. So I can't replace it by static tag

Comment: @maxxy in that case can you post an additional example?

Comment: I just edited my post. Thx for your help. according to my exemple that why i thought about stacks (but might be a better way? )